# XCODE iphone 6 plus and 6s plus shows warning when display UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm a newbie in iOS development. I was trying to display a `UIAlertController` when a button is clicked (The storyboard is empty, there's only 1 button in the storyboard), using below code

```
@IBAction func showAlert(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Create new",
    message: "Hi",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
  )

  let createAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

  alert.addAction(createAction)
  alert.addAction(cancelAction)
  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
    $0.placeholder = "Test placeholder"
  }

  presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

iphone 5, 5s, 6, 6s do not show warnings, however iphone 6plus and 6s plus shows warning

> 2015-10-20 22:38:54.007 TestApp[3128:48601] the behavior of the
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 
>   2015-10-20 22:38:54.008 TestApp[3128:48601] the item height must be less than the
>   height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom
>   values, minus the content insets top and bottom values. 2015-10-20
>   22:38:54.008 TestApp[3128:48601] The relevant
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fd6b8582d90>, and it
>   is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout:
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout:   0x7fd6b8582d90>.

If I remove the text field on `UIAlertController` or I remove the 2 buttons (keep the text field displayed), it does not show warnings. Any explanation why this happens? How to fix the warning?

Comment: This may be stupid but try adding the text field before the two actions.

Comment: @rmaddy it still shows the warning. Anyway I just tried adding 2 text fields and it does not show warnings on all platforms, I added it before and after the statements of adding the 2 actions (`Default` and `Cancel`)

Comment: Submit a bug to Apple. Include a simple test app that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yea I'm about to submit the bug, thanks for the response.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm curious, if you have time to run the code above, does this happen to you too?

Comment: For what it's worth I found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18294) thread. One person did fix by manually setting contentInset to UIEdgeInsetsZero but it looks like a bug report was filed there as well.

Comment: I have met this, but You cannot find the collection view to set UIEdgeInsetsZero

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try:

```
yourAlertController.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

just before presenting it with `presentViewController:`

**edit:** I have submitted this bug to Apple

Comment: This gets rid of the warning - we should still be submitting the bug to apple since this line should not be needed.

Comment: Where to check the Apple reported bug status?

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue in my screen for only iphon6 plus screen. Please check, if you are not passing empty title, if title is empty , pass it nil like :

```
UIAlertController *confirmAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:displayMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

instead of

```
  UIAlertController *confirmAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:displayMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

it fixed my problem. Good luck..